# It is showed up two same apps button in UIDocumentInteractionController popup

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction, ios8-share-extension

I appologize for my low level English.

I developed Share Extension in my app to support the extention added at iOS8.
But, my app has been already showing up in UIDocumentInteractionController popup.
So, my app has been showing up two items for same app after supporting share extension:"xyz, copy to xyz".
'xyz' is my app name.

I want to make to show up only one item at UIDocumentInteractionController popup menu.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have suffer this familiar situation when i research share extention.When i open safari to share web url to my APP, the safari's share menu has two same APP button.Then i click Product-->Clean solve this problem.This seems caches should be blame for it. I also apologize for my poor English.

Comment: Thank you for comment, however, the cause is not that. There is a fundamental iOS feature for cause, I think. The almost apps installed in my iPhone have this same problem.